# How do I change the resolution on an Asus 101mt?

Tags: resolution

I've been looking for a fix, but no luck. my Asus 101mt has a maximum resolution of 1024x768, but I cannot select this in "Displays" since it is not an option.

I have added this resolution before, but now I can't seem to find the same information.  I just did a clean install with 12.04. I am also dual booting with Win 7.

---

I have been trying to get this working for a while and now I switched to 12.10.  I tried using xrandr, but this is as far as I get.

```
barzyk@barzyk-T101MT:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

barzyk@barzyk-T101MT:~$ cvt 1024 768
# 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync

barzyk@barzyk-T101MT:~$ xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync

barzyk@barzyk-T101MT:~$ xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1024x768_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Dou you have the graphic card driver installed?

Comment: I do! It looks like I have this as graphics: Intel® IGD x86/MMX/SSE2.  With windows I was able to customize the resolution by messing with the regedit stuff. I'm looking to do the same thing with 12.04. My monitor can take the larger resolution, AND all of the side panel stuff in my Chromeo is huge. I should probably find a way to make that stuff smaller.   Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Have you installed the package `mesa-utils`?

Comment: Yes I have! That's how I got the computer to recognize what graphics I was running. before I installed that, it said graphics unknown.

Comment: I still haven't found an answer to this. Anyone who can help, please do!  It's really annoying that I can't make the screen any bigger, especially since when menus pop up, I can't even hit the buttons on the bottom like "cancel" or "save." Please Help!

Comment: Please provide the output `sudo lspci`

Comment: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express

Comment: Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI

Comment: Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and let me know how this works or you:

Create a rudimentary xorg.conf using the following commands:

> cd /etc/X11 Xorg –configure
>
> mv ~/xorg.conf.new xorg.conf
>
> vi xorg.conf

Use PAGE-DOWN to scroll the text until you see the line reading `Section “Device”`.
Using the DOWN arrow, move the cursor to the indented line that starts with the
word `“Driver”`. It may look like the following:

> Driver “fbdev”

Move the cursor to the first letter inside the quotation marks and type “cw” – must
be lowercase letters – and the word inside the quotation marks will disappear but
the quotation marks will remain. Notice that “-- INSERT --” will appear on the
bottom line of the screen.

Type vesa within the quotation marks still on the screen.

Press ESC.

Move the cursor down until you see the line reading

> Section “Screen”

Indented are several lines. Move the cursor to the line below the line reading

> Monitor “Monitor0”

Type the letter `“O”` – that is, a capital-O – and a blank line opens between the two
lines. The cursor appears at the beginning of this blank line.

Press TAB to align the cursor with the word `“Monitor”` on the line above and then
type `DefaultDepth 24`.

Notice that both words are capitalized, but there is no space between `“Default”` and
`“Depth”` although there is at least one space between `“Depth”` and the number 24.

Press ESC.

1. Type “G” – must be a capital-G – and the cursor will go to the bottom line of the

file. You should see a subsection for “Display” having a depth of 24. If you do not
see that and, in case you passed it, using PAGE-UP or the UP arrow to scroll back
does not reveal it, you can add one as follows:

a. Put the cursor on the unindented “EndSection” up against the left margin.

b. Type an “O” – must be capital-O – to open a blank line above the unindented
“EndSection” line.

c. Using TAB to indent each line as follows, type the following text:

> SubSection “Display”
>
> Viewport 0 0
>
> Depth 24
>
> EndSubSection

Press ESC.

Type “ZZ” – must be two capital-Z letters – to save and quit the editor.

Run the command `startx` to begin the X Window System as the root user.
Eventually, root’s desktop should appear.

Check the resolution that X selected by default using System -> Preferences ->
Hardware -> Screen Resolution and change it to the appropriate setting as needed.

Open a terminal using Applications -> System Tools -> Terminal.

Run the program glxgears to see an approximation of your graphics frame
updating speed.

Quit X using the logout option in the System menu or using CTRL-ALT-BACKSPACE.

[Source](http://download.intel.com/embedded/324962.pdf#iid=4707)

Comment: I put the first command in, and this is what I got: Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync       30.0-62.0
    VertRefresh     50.0-70.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Modes     "1024x768" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Comment: That's the video configuration, did you ran `startx` ?

Comment: When I ran it, I got this output...X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.

Comment: Try running it as the normal user

Comment: I put in the second command and I got this: barzyk@barzyk-Asus:/etc/X11$ mv ~/xorg.conf.new xorg.conf
mv: cannot stat `/home/barzyk/xorg.conf.new': No such file or directory

Comment: Did this command worked? `cd /etc/X11 Xorg –configure` it should create a xorg.conf.new file. Nevertheless what you need is a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file that has the display option set for the resolution you need.